# Element hides but parent() not

Tags: jquery, parent

I am trying to hide the container of an image when it can't be fournd. So far this workes which hide the "image not found" icon:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(function(img){
    img.onerror = function(){
        this.style.display='none';
    };
   })
});
```

But when I change this line:

```
this.display='none';
```

to

```
this.parent().display='none';
```

it's not working. 
How can I hide the container image?

Comment: Have you tried changing it to `this.parentElement.style.display='none'`? Btw, `this.display='none';` wouldn't work either. It's `this.style.display='none';`. Cheers!

Comment: You have tagged jQuery, and i am not sure do you use it? Your example code is vanilla JS, and you have an answer already... but...if you use jQuery - 'this' is not jQuery object, hence it doesn't have parent() method - so for jQuery: $(this).parent().hide() should do the job....

Comment: Use $(this).parent().hide() if you want to achieve it via jquery, provided you have referenced jquery library and it is available before this code executes. With your provided code you should go with  this.parentElement.style.display = 'none'; that is already answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't jQuery, just good ol' DOM.

```
this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
```